# Consuming Sharepoint web services with ADFS claims-based authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, sharepoint, adfs, adfs2.0

We've recently switched one of our Sharepoint instance to use ADFS claims authentication instead of windows authentication. And now I can't seem to get the Copy service to work correctly from the server.

I've tried many methods, but none worked. Including the one found [here](http://www.tonytestasworld.com/post/2009/06/04/How-To-Authenticate-and-Use-SharePoint-Web-Services-in-an-FBA-SharePoint-site.aspx) suggested by another answer here on SO. In this case I get a 400 bad request when I call the login method.

I don't necessarely need to impersonate the user, but that would be great.
Any idea how I should do this?

Things that I have on the server to help authenticate:

- IClaimsIdentity containing all the claims issued by ADFS
- Bootstrap token (I tried to authenticate using it but no luck so far)
- credentials for the system account (that I used when trying to authenticate with Sharepoint's authentication service)